# Why is my server not booting? Stalls at `Mountpoint-cache hash table entries`

Tags: boot, server, grub2, kernel

I've been unable to boot my server for the last few days, and I can't figure out why. I'm suspecting that the CPU has gone bad, but would like some advice going forward with my troubleshooting.

The following indicates *Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS*, but I copied this from a previous question of mine six months ago. I'm unable to run the command currently. However, I've run updates regularly, so the server is most likely *Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS*.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
```

**tl;dr**

Server got a kernel panic. After reboot, I'm stuck at the following screen:

[image: stuck at Mountpoint-cache hash table entries]

---

**Server specs**

Supermicro S8SAX motherboard

CPU: Intel CORE i7 920

Memory: 16GB

Redundant power supply

**History**

- On Saturday 10/28/23 I replaced failing hard drive in a RAID 6 array.
- I monitored occasionally over the next several hours as the drive was rebuilt. No errors resulted.
- I ran `sudo nala update` and `sudo nala upgrade` to update the server. It indicated that an updated kernel was going to be installed.

  - Previous version: `5.15.0-84-generic`
  - New version: `5.15.0-86-generic`
- After upgrade, server required reboot. I ran `sudo reboot` and walked away.
- I didn't look at the server again until Monday 10/30/23 when I tried to SSH into it. I was unable to.
- Once back at the physical machine, I saw the following screen showing a kernel panic:
  [image: kernel panic]
- I forced the computer to shutdown and rebooted. I got the following screen where the boot stalls:
  [image: stuck at Mountpoint-cache hash table entries]

**Troubleshooting**

- I attempted to boot into the older kernel: `5.15.0.86-generic`. Would not boot. Stuck at same screen.
- I attempted to boot into recovery mode for both kernels: `5.15.0-84-generic` & `5.15.0-86-generic`. Would not boot. Stuck at same screen.
- I attempted to boot from a LIVE USB stick, both Ubuntu 22.04 and Clonezilla. Would not boot. Stuck on black screen.
- I ran memtest+. No errors resulted.

I was unable to work on the server yesterday. Today, after leaving it powered off since Monday, I booted it up, and it actually booted.

- I ran `sudo nala update` and `sudo nala upgrade`. It indicated an updated kernel was available: `5.15.0-88-generic`. I proceeded and it appeared successful. However, it did not indicate a reboot was required. I rebooted anyways.
- The server rebooted, but Grub menu did not show. Once in the console, I ran `uname -r` and it indicated `5.15.0-84-generic`
- I updated grub to once again show the menu with a timeout of 5 seconds. I rebooted.
- Grub menu shows, but only shows `5.15.0-84-generic` & `5.15.0-86-generic` kernels. I select first option, but process gets stuck again at the same screen with `Mountpoint-cache hash table entries`.
- Forced a power off and rebooted.
- Grub menu shows this time, but timeout is now 24 seconds (reset on its own).
- But...I'm stuck again at the same screen with `Mountpoint-cache hash table entries`.

  - I'm unable to boot into any kernel.
  - Grub menu does not show `5.15.0-88-generic`
  - Grub menu still only shows `5.15.0-84-generic` & `5.15.0-86-generic`
- I'm unable to proceed any further.

**Conclusion**

I'm suspecting this is a hardware issue and mostly likely a failing CPU. But I'm not exactly sure and was hoping someone could provide more info on how to solve this.

Comment: As the issue was a stuck CPU fan and thermal shutdown I am closing this question as unable to reproduce etc. https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64666214